# Making charts in excel programmatically

Tags: c++, excel, xll

I have an XLL made with the help of the XLW wrapper for Excel's C API.  I would like to be able to programmatic make charts in excel using data stored in some objects in the XLL.  Is this possible and if so, what is the best way to do it?  I believe one way to do is through COM but would like to avoid it if at all possible.
  Currently using Excel 2007 on Windows 7 and VS2010.

Edit:  In general what API does excel expose that supports programmatic charting?  Can anyone point me towards some documentation?

Edit2: Since I'm not getting any hits I will try to give a little more detail  abaout what I'm trying to do.  I want to call a formula from Excel like =PlotCurve("CurvreHandle") and I want to get a curve object stored in memory and owned by the XLL (unmanaged code), get an some data from it and display it in a chart somewhere on the sheet where the PlotCurve was made. From what I have been able to gleam so far, the C API that XLW is wrapping offers no support for the second part of the problem so I need to go to either COM (which I have no idea how to mix with the already running C api) or some .net interop which I also don't know how to do . If someone has ever done something like this or knows of a safe and stable way to do this, I would love to hear it.

Comment: I have a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265807/how-to-create-free-form-graphics-in-microsoft-office ... could you figure out what to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://xll.codeplex.com and Excel4/Excel12. The function ExcelX can be used to handle the memory management. The command to use is xlcChartWizard.

Answer (score 0):

To create, modify, save charts in Excel programmatically you can use the C++ classes in the [`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms262200%28v=office.11%29.aspx) namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Could you elaborate a little though.  I have an excel session that loads an unmanaged DLL.  Now I need to call some .Net service.  How does the service know where to return to?  I.e, how does it know about the original excel session?